# Sort sql results by Month with unix

Tags: mysql, sql, unix-timestamp

here's what im trying to achive:

i have 2 sql tables:
transactions and payplans
bellow is the structures of 2 tables:

transactions

```
uid | plan | date       | payid | status
------------------------------------
12  | 3    | 1388534400 | 334 | 1
699 | 4    | 1388214400 | 335 | 1
```

payplans:

```
plan | plan_price
-------------------
3    | 9.99
4    | 19.99
```

with this query:

```
SELECT SUM(plan_price) 
  FROM transations AS t
       INNER JOIN payplans AS p
                  ON t.plan = p.plan
 WHERE t.status = '1'
```

i was able to calculate total sum of all "plan_price" rows,
but i would like to have the price sum for every month starting jan 2013
for example:

jan-13 | 9.99

feb-13 | 29.99
etc.

Comment: Which rdbms you are using? Also, please, provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE transactions;` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE payplans;` or `DESC transactions;` and `DESC payplans;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySQL

```
SELECT date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(t.date), '%b-%y') as mnth,
       SUM(plan_price) 
  FROM transations AS t
       INNER JOIN payplans AS p
                  ON t.plan = p.plan
 WHERE t.status = '1'
 GROUP BY mnth;
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c8533/2)

1. You converting unix_timestamp to date using [`FROM_UNIXTIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)
2. formatting it into 'MON-YY' format with [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)
3. then grouping by month.

Comment: Thanks, but im using mysql